# How to pick an object from a list at random in csh

Tags: csh

So as the title suggests, I am trying to pick an object from a list at random in my csh script.

What I have so far is:

```
set list = ( \
           "string1" \
           "string2" \
           "string3" \
           )

while [1] do
    random_object = "I picked ${list [$RANDOM % ${#list[@]} ] }"
    echo $random_object

    sleep 1 #test code so I can see it randomise 
done
```

All I get is "[1]: No match."

Anyone got a solution?

Comment: You script is wrong at almost every statement. Your `while` loop is invalid, you for to use `set` for the assignment to `random_object` , `$RANDOM` is a bash thing, not csh, the way you access lists/arrays is also a bash thing. The only *correct* things are the `echo` and `sleep` statements....

Comment: So I had issue finding csh help and (wrongly, it seems) assumed bash was similar. What is the correct way of writing it then?

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to call in the help of some standard UNIX utilities.

For example:

```
#!/bin/csh -f

set list = ( \
           "string1" \
           "string2" \
           "string3" \
           )
while (1)
  dd if=/dev/random of=/tmp/random count=1 bs=4 >& /dev/null
  set random_nr = `od -t u4 /tmp/random | awk '{print $2;}'`
  @ random_index = $random_nr % $#list + 1
  set random_object = "I picked $list[$random_index]"
  echo "$random_object ($random_nr)"
  sleep 1
end
```

Comment: Never used `od` before; it's neat. Refinements in a separate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly what @fork2execve suggested. However, there are some simplifications that you can make. You don't need to call awk, nor dd; and you don't need a temporary file. You can simply do:

```
set random_nr=`od -D -N1 -An /dev/urandom`
```

Comment: Hm, be careful with these 'new' options if you want your script to run on all (old) UNIX variations. AIX and Solaris are fine but HP-UX 11.23 doesn't support `-D` so I recommend you stick to `-t u4`. If you need to support BSD 4.3 then it doesn't support any of these.